# Can dataTaskWithRequest be completed before new view controller load?

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I am trying to do post request using dataTaskWithRequest. I have two view controllers, LoginViewController and SecondViewController. In the LoginViewController I have submit button to submit form login and then go to the second view. However in the button action function I called dataTaskWithRequest to get authentication.

How can dataTaskWithRequest complete his task before SecondViewController load?

Comment: This is too broad. Are you familiar with the details on how to create the `NSURLRequest`? Are you familiar with how to hook up a button to an `@IBAction`? You have to narrow this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that the login view controller's button should *not* be a segue to the second view controller. Instead, it should simply be an `@IBAction` which performs the authentication with the `dataTaskWithRequest`, and only if you determined it was successful in the `completionHandler` closure, would it programmatically transition to the next view controller.

So, let's pick that apart:

1. Hook up button in login scene to an `@IBAction`, which creates a request, initiates it, and in the completion block determines if it was successful and if so, tells the :

   ```
   @IBAction func didTapLoginButton(sender: UIButton) {
       let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "loginurl")!)
       request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
       request.HTTPBody = ...

       let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
           if data == nil {
               // handle error here
               println("\(error)")
           } else {
               // parse response here and determine if successful

               var loginSuccessful: Bool = ...

               if loginSuccessful {
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueToSecond", sender: sender)
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       task.resume()
   }
   ```

   Clearly, there's a lot more you might want to do there (e.g. tell the user if the authorization failed, etc.), but this illustrates the moving parts:

   - create request;
   - in completionHandler, see if authorization succeeded; and
   - anything you do with the UI must be dispatched back to the main queue.
2. Note, the above assumes you have a segue from the login scene to the second scene. You can do this by <kbd>control</kbd> drag from the view controller icon above the login scene to the second scene:

   [image]

   When that's done, select the segue and give it a unique storyboard id (the same one you will use in the `@IBAction` code, above):

   [image]